# Connecting Team Foundation Server (TFS) with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, tfs

I am new to Xcode and TFS. Can someone please explain me how I can connect TFS 2013 with Xcode to maintain repositories or give me a link which has full details from the beginning?

Comment: Xcode does not support TFS, you will need a separate TFS client: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608504/is-there-a-mac-client-for-microsoft-team-foundation-server

Comment: but XCode supports Git and TFS offers Git.
@Hanushka can you add details on versions so we can give proper answers

Comment: @Giulio Vian Xcode version is 5.1 and tfs 2013

Comment: TFS? Is at least 2013? or is VSO?

Comment: @Giulio Vian tfs 2013 :)

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for the quick response (Y)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The idea is to use Git as your version control and push your changes to a central Repo hosted in TFS. The TFS Administrator should create a Project with Git support and grant your account permissions.
Most of TFS features are accessible through a web interface, so you can have task/bug tracking, associate them with your commits and so on.

To start learning, I would not recommend the [TFS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fda2bad5.aspx) nor the [VSO](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/cross-platform/share-your-xcode-projects-vs) documentation for your specific case, but would start from a couple of videos: [Using Xcode in Git Projects Using Team Foundation Server 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Launch-2013/AT110) and [Deep Dive into Git with Team Foundation Server](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/3-590).

Comment: Thanks @Guilio Vian. I will try to learn by wathing these videos.

Comment: While Guilio answer is accurate, just keep in mind that GIT Support in TFS hasn't always existed, so it's entirely possible that working with older versions of Visual Studio or Team Foundation Server that GIT will not be available.

Comment: Correct, in fact I asked the OP which TFS version he was using before answering.
I edited the question to help future readers getting the proper context.

Comment: @GiulioVian Thanks for everything. I got my work done because of you. Thanks again. cheers (Y)