# xcode support TFS(Team Foundation Server) for version control on mac OS? & How to setup TFS on xcode?

Tags: xcode, tfs, version-control

My project just on my local no git or anyelse. 
So can i use TFS with xcode on Mac OS? If yes, how to setup TFS on Xcode?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting Team Foundation Server (TFS) with Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209310/connecting-team-foundation-server-tfs-with-xcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can share your Xcode projects in TFS using both a Git repository and a TFVC repository.

[Share your code in Git using Xcode](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/share-your-code-in-git-xcode):

1. Clone Git repository from TFS
2. Move your code into the local Git repository.
3. In Xcode, commit your changes locally.
4. Push your changes to your team project's repository.

[Share your code in TFVC using Xcode](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/code/share-your-code-in-tfvc-xcode):

1. Download and configure Git-tf
2. Add Git-tf and the Java runtime to your path.
3. Go to the root of your local repository.
4. To share your Git repository in TFS, configure the connection and check in your code.
5. After you commit changes to your local Git repository, and you're ready to share them in TFS, check them in.

Comment: Thanks for answer Cece - MSFT